# How to get Rows values as comma or semi colon sepeared values as output in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table name employee
Emp_id      Emp_name     emp_language
1           john         Java
2           Ragul        Python
3           April        Java
```

I need a query to get output like

```
1,john,Java
2,Ragul,Python
3,April,Java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`CONCAT_WS()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function such as

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',Emp_id,Emp_name,emp_language)
  FROM employee
```

which is similar to **`CONCAT()`** but no need to repeat the seperator by keeping as the first argument.

Comment: i'm getting "no function by the concat_ws was found" . is there any other way to solve this. i'm having more than 60 columns in my table.

Comment: @Badcoder Are you sure that your DBMS is MySQL ? Btw, what's the version of it?

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a simple and good way and of course it answers the question. But maybe one should add coalesce to replace null values. Without that, the result could be bad to read: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2e9293adc424d452f5c7daea3724794

Comment: This will be a decision to take by the author of the question. I just want to hint this possible "issue". As I said, your propose of course answers the question.